# Can a git repository be cloned directly into a github account?

Tags: git, github

I work in multiple different computers and use github sync my projects. It is extremely useful when I create a repository from scratch or fork from github. Is it possible to clone a repository directly into github so all my local clones remote the github repo and in return, github repo remotes the original one.

Addendum:
I am quiet new to git and what I actually want is to keep my own work in sync without interacting with the original repository(other than pulling updates).

I came up with this scheme:

```
          github
    *<----->*<-------> PC1
original    ^--------> Pc2
            ^--------> PC3
```

where <---> shows pulling and pushing. Maybe I am approaching this from a wrong angle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the github repo and push one of your local clones to it.  You'll probably need `git push git@github.com:... master`.  Then, use `git remote add <name> <url>` in all your local clones.

I don't see why you need the github repo to have your repository as a remote--you won't be using that copy of the repo with a working directory.

Comment: You may need to do a "git pull git@github.com:USERNAME/REPO_NAME master" first so that everything is merged together correctly

Answer (score 0):

```
git remote add gh ssh://user@github/whatever
git push gh --all
```